# Como criar um comando que realize somas usando latex

Tags: latex

Preciso colocar a numeração de páginas no documento que estou criando, mas esse documento começa a partir da página 20 por exemplo, então eu deveria usar um comando que fizesse algo como:

```
\cfoot{Página \thepage+20 de (Número total de Páginas)}
```

onde \thepage+20 teria que exibir a página atual + 20, como proceder?!

Comment: Para isso não bastaria definir o valor inicial da página como 20? Acho que o `\setcounter{page}` faz isso.

Comment: obrigado, deu certo!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para controlar a numeração das páginas, basta definir o valor do respectivo contador. No LaTeX, basta você utilizar logo no início do arquivo para definir que o contador deve iniciar em 20:

```
\setcounter{page}{20}
```

Assim, a primeira página será a 20 e as subsequentes será contado normalmente, adicionando 1 ao contador.

Referências na rede Stack Exchange:

[How can I set the page number to any needed value?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87525/124462)